Difference between time.sleep() and threading.timer() accuracy and efficiency in Python
Let's say I have a Python script which is designed to wait for a specific amount of time in milliseconds and then press a key on the keyboard. Should I use threading.Timer() or should I just do it with time.sleep()? Which one is more accurate in terms of pressing the key on time and which one is more efficient?
Also, please let me know if there are better and more accurate ways to do this.

How accurate do you need it to be?

Precision is platform-dependent.  In particular, no computer running multiple processes is going to guarantee you that it will wake you up at precisely the moment you want to be woken up.
If you're really desperate, a busy loop with time.perf_counter() is your bet bet, but you still can't guarantee your program will be running at the precise moment you need it to.

@SIGHUP A delay of approximately 100ms is fine.

You seem confused by your own requirements. You look for accuracy and yet say "approximately 100ms". If it's OK for your program / thread to block, then sleep(0.1) will suffice

threading.Timer() runs in a separate thread, which means it won't block your main program. However, it can be less precise due to thread scheduling overhead and context switching.
time.sleep() is more accurate for short durations (milliseconds range) since it doesn't involve thread creation overhead. However, it blocks the entire program while waiting.
A third option worth considering is using Python's asyncio, which can provide good timing accuracy without blocking.
